# How to save all modification operations for custom list in database?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have custom list in SharePoint 2013, there are many edit operation on each item for the list , I want to save all the operation’s in database , then I can  extract to  Excel file (like report for these operations ).

My question is:

Can I do it with No-Code solution ? if yes , how?

If I need to do it with Code, what’s an appropriate solution to do it , using ( client-side object model (CSOM) , build an application by .Net ,etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the out of the box [audit feature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx) of Microsoft SharePoint Server to track which users have taken what actions on the sites, content types, lists, libraries, list items, and library files of site collections.

As a **site collection administrator**, you can retrieve the history of actions taken by a particular user and can also retrieve the history of actions taken during a particular date range. For example, you can determine which users edited a specific document and when they did this.

The audit log captures the following information for the events that are selected to be audited.

- Site from which an event originated
- Item ID, type, name, and location
- User ID associated with the event
- Event type, date, time, and source
- Action taken on the item

[How to view the audit log](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx)

How ever you can also choose for a custom approach by using an [event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx). This way you can decided which operation you want to save and where you want to save this data.

There are many events you can use see the [Table of SharePoint Events, Event Receivers, and Event Hosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408183%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: The data in Excel file display as links not real  meaningful information

Comment: That was the no code solution. You can also create an event receiver saving all youre operation in what ever format you want

Comment: Added some extra information

Comment: You can use content modifications audit report available out of box in sharepoint

Comment: create an event receiver, is it Code solution?

Comment: Yes thats a code solution